# Issue on updating IntelliJ version 13.0.4 SDK Error

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

Problem: (This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of IntelliJ IDEA. Please update IntelliJ IDEA).

I tried to update my IntelliJ v 13.0.4 SDK, but after doing it all my layouts display is not working. I look for solution search for some related issues, but it did not help me much. Even though I tried to change the layout API versions, it did not change the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Try to download the latest Intellij version. https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/ .
Maybe the old Intellij version does not support the latest release of android sdk. I encountered the same issue the other day.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, It works fine now. I updated my IntelliJ v 3.0.4 to IntelliJ v 3.1.5. Now all my layouts works Alright now.Thanks for helping.